# Is it possible to manually disconnect Django's database connection?

Tags: python, django

In order to debug a problem with Django's mysql connection timing out during a long celery task ([Long celery task causes MySQL timeout in Django - options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483404/long-celery-task-causes-mysql-timeout-in-django-options)) I would like to manually close the connection so I can see if my reconnect attempt works.

Is this possible?

Comment: I actually don't know for sure if it will work out but you can try out something like this:
Kill the connection as is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932503/how-to-kill-mysql-connections
And then check if it will try to reconnect. I am not sure if kill will do, but maybe this thread will also help you:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/mysql-client-believes-theyre-in-a-transaction-gets-killed-wreaks-havoc
The question is pretty interesting, i'll be waiting for solution )